# How to perform binary comp on long binary values (over 64 bit)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, bit-manipulation

Like in the subject and here is problem synopsis:
I have some 480 different steel types. Some steels can be converted into another through heat and/or chemical processing. Moreover, over years specifications and technologies change and some mutations become impossible and others become available. My production environment needs to be freely and easily able to add or remove individual steel types as they search for them in db.

Solution: I wanted to use bit masks to deliver the solution. Each steel type would be assigned individual significant bit position. Steel types that can go together would have their bit masks combined creating default group search masks. As use modifies the group at runtime, bit mask of individual steel type would be added or subtracted from default group search mask. When executed, query would perform binary ANDing against individual bit masks of all items in specified table and return all like `searchMask & individualMask <> 0` I successfully use this principle for other applications but bitwise operators in SQL can not be applied to a pair of binary fields. The largest data type I can use is 64 bit bigint.

Thus the question, how can I perform binary ANDing on two binary fields in T-SQL or what other solution could I use for above problem without creating arbitrary groups?

Comment: Consider a SQL CLR datatype or function to operate on varbinary values. With this strategy you can't index effectively anyway.

Answer (score 1):

An idea can be to split the mask in chunk of 64 bit and check every couple of chunck separately then add the result of the bitwise operation, a proof of concept that can be converted to a function is

```
DECLARE @a VARBINARY(200) = Cast(Replicate(Char(128), 200) AS VARBINARY(200)) 
DECLARE @b VARBINARY(200) = Cast(Replicate(Char(130), 200) AS VARBINARY(200)); 

WITH splitter AS (
  SELECT Cast(Cast(LEFT(@a, 64) AS VARBINARY(64)) AS BIGINT) a
       , Cast(Cast(LEFT(@b, 64) AS VARBINARY(64)) AS BIGINT) b 
       , _and = Cast(0 AS BIT)
       , b = 1
       , rev = Cast(Ceiling(Len(@a) / 64.0) AS INT) 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT Cast(Cast(Substring(@a, b * 64, 64) AS VARBINARY(64)) AS BIGINT) a
       , Cast(Cast(Substring(@b, b * 64, 64) AS VARBINARY(64)) AS BIGINT) b 
       , _and = _and | Cast(a & b AS BIT), 
       , b = b + 1, 
       , rev = rev - 1 
  FROM   splitter 
  WHERE  b * 64 < Len(@a)
) 
SELECT _and | Cast(a & b AS BIT) 
FROM   splitter 
WHERE  rev = 1
```

the recursive `CTE`, with a lot of `CAST`, generate a row for every 64 byte and execute the bitwise `AND` to the two previous chunk, the `CAST` to `BIT` is to be sure that the value can be added in the type space, the bitwise `OR` is used because `BIT` cannot be summed.

The code assume that the two values have the same dimension, if the opposite is true @a should be the shorter one, to have less iteration in the recursive `CTE`.